# Prove that: $\delta_{1}-\delta_{-1} \notin L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

I'm going to prove that there is no $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$\langle \delta_{1}-\delta_{-1},\varphi\rangle =\int f\varphi $$

for all test functions $\varphi$ (i.e. $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}$),
where
$$\delta_a= \operatorname{Distribution Dirac}\quad\text{at}\quad a$$
that is
$$\langle \delta_{a},\varphi\rangle = \varphi(a)$$
for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

My attempt:

Suppose $\delta_{1}-\delta_{1} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

$$\langle \delta_{1}-\delta_{1} ,\varphi \rangle = \varphi(1)-\varphi(-1)$$
Mean!
$$\exists c>0 , |\varphi(1)-\varphi(-1)|≤c \|\varphi\|_{L^{2}} $$
Here I need find a sequence of continuous functions to get a contradiction!

Can you assist? I'm grateful!

---

Thanks!

Comment: The first definition of the Dirac distribution is wrong. That would be a definition of the function which is almost surely zero, i.e. a function which is indeed $L^2$. Perhaps you can remove this part from your question. Since $\delta$ is fundamentally defined as distribution, your question probably should read "does there exists an $L^2$-function $f$ such that

Comment: The first definition of the Dirac distribution is wrong. That would be a definition of the function which is almost surely zero, i.e. a function which is indeed $L^2$. Perhaps you can remove this part from your question. Since $\delta$ is fundamentally defined as distribution, your question probably should read "does there exists an $L^2$-function $f$ such that $\langle \delta_1-\delta_{-1}, \varphi\rangle=\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x)f(x) dx$ dir all $\varphi\in\C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$...?

Comment: Can you explain more ? How I prove that , i know dirac is not a function

Comment: If you define $L^2$ as the completion of $C^0_c$ for the $\|.\|_2$ norm then it is mostly immediate that $f\in L^2$ implies $f\ast n 1_{[0,1/n]}\to f$ in $\|.\|_2$ norm, if $\delta \in L^2$ then in particular $\delta \ast n 1_{[0,1/n]}= n 1_{[0,1/n]}$ has a bounded $\|.\|_2$ norm which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

What you really mean to ask is this.  Show there doesn't exist a function $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that for any test function $h$
$$ (\delta_{1} - \delta_{-1})(h) := h(1) - h(-1) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) h(x) \, dx .$$
Suppose there does exist such an $f$.  If $h$ is any test function, find a sequence of test functions $h_n$ for which $h_n(1) = h_n(-1) = 0$ such that ${\|h - h_n\|}_2 \to 0$.
Thus
$$ \int _{\mathbb R} f(x) h(x) \, dx = 0 ,$$
and we have a contradiction.